# Connection to MongoDb with express on M1 Mac not working

Tags: mongodb, express, apple-m1

I installed mongoDB with

```
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
```

I started mongoDB with

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

on `brew services list` I get:

```
Name              Status  User        File
emacs             stopped
mongodb-community started laurenz ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
unbound           stopped
```

On my express server I used this code to connect to mongoDB:

```
connectToServer: function (callback) {

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => { 
  console.error(error)
  callback(error)
})
```

}

When opening MongoDB Compass I can connect to MongoDB and also see my table.
The same code works on my Intel iMac just fine.

This is the error I get when starting my server.js:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
    at /Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:10
    at /Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1153:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:331:20)
    at Object.connectToServer (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/db/conn.js:16:14)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/server.js:16:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
    at /Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:10
    at /Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1153:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:331:20)
    at Object.connectToServer (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/db/conn.js:16:14)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/server.js:16:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
    }
}
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
    at /Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:10
    at /Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1153:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:331:20)
    at Object.connectToServer (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/db/conn.js:16:14)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/server.js:16:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 47955814,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:293:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/laurenz/uni_workspace/omm-project-ws2122/be/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:267:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v17.0.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Does anyone have a similar problem or knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was.

I replaced my connection call with:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  console.log('Connected to Database')

  console.log(client);
})
```

This seems to work out. I don't know why it didn't work with localhost, but now it's working.

Comment: Thank you! I was running out of patience with this, Compass and mongo could connect to my DB fine but mongoose would just refuse with ECONNREFUSED. Changing to IP fixed it instantly

Comment: Fixed it here too.  ‍♂️